# Disassemble default iOS apps with otool

Tags: iphone, ios, assembly, disassembly, otool

When I try to disassemble the stock iOS apps (not app store ones) with otool it isn't split into different methods. It's just one massive section. Here's the command I'm using:

`otool -tV theApp.app/theApp >~/Desktop/output.txt`
Is there a way to get the disassembly split into methods?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there isn't. Those applications have been stripped, which means they contain no information about where functions begin or end. However, since objective-c is dynamic, any objective-c methods will have their name and address in the objective-c segment. You can get this information using `otool -ov`, but it is easier to interpret it if you use [class-dump-z](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z), which provides objective-c headers and will include the addresses of each method if you use the `-A` option. After you have the addresses, you can go through your file and separate it into methods manually.