# Is it possible to reverse engineering to get the original source code from .ipa file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reverse-engineering, ipa

I am currently a iPhone apps developer and trying to learn the mechanism of generating the audio impulses by extracting the current ipa solutions and github solutions

When using Hopper to extract , only recompiled and incomplete assembly codes are generated. We cannot see any objective classes for further exploration .

Are there any alternatives to achieve this aim ?

Comment: Yes it is possible , I don't know how but apple can do this.I know this because they rejected my app due to some hidden code which is against app store rule.

Comment: Agreed, Apple somehow knows you use Private API or not, thus I think there is a secret way to reverse engineer IPA.

Comment: You might want to check reverseingineering forums here,http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source

Comment: there's no magic on know if you use private API. it doesn't mean apple can reverse your IPA do the source code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458544/disassemble-default-ios-apps-with-otool ... Basically no, you will not be able to reverse to source, but there are tools you can use to figure out where different functions start and end, which you can then read if you know assembly.  Honestly it'll be faster for you to Google for what you're trying to learn, then write some test code and ask questions here.

Comment: well,if apple can't then in my case, how apple knew that I am using webservice to hide some functionality dynamically ?

Comment: By Network Capture maybe ?

Comment: They don't have to get your source code to know which symbols your app is linked against, which strings it contains, and which classes is uses. For example, check your output of `nm` or `otool` against your app binary. Why do you need SPI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are such things as [decompilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler), but not sure if there's one for iOS/Objective-C. Anyway you won't get back the original source, variable names, comments, etc. So it's still a slog.

Instead of reversing someone's app why not ask "how to" questions on stackoverflow? ;-)

Also, you can see the classes defined in the program, try `nm`.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, the IPA file doesn't contain any source code.  Which is a good thing, I think most developers want privacy with their material.